# Enable gridsplitter when both expander IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a grid with three rows.

First and last rows are occupied by expander and the second row is occupied by gridsplitter.

I want to accomplish a functionality to gridsplitter. I want the gridsplitter to be visible only when both my expander is unfolded  `Visibility ="visible"`.

**How can I set this behavior to the gridsplitter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [MultiDataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger.conditions?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Here is the sample for your scenario.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Expander IsExpanded="True" x:Name="exp1">
        <TextBlock Text="In Expander 1" />
    </Expander>
    <Expander IsExpanded="True" x:Name="exp2">
       <TextBlock Text="In Expander 2" />   
    </Expander>    
    <GridSplitter >
        <GridSplitter.Style>
            <Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=exp1,  Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=exp2,  Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />

                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </GridSplitter>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What I need to change if my **second expander** is in **another XAML** file. How can I connect them? @gopichandar

Comment: @TomThomas You need to have `DependencyProperty` on the other view that will be used in this view to bind values.

Comment: I had done that but there is some problem. I have asked about it in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764648/binding-two-user-controls-using-multidatatrigger can you have a look!?